# Can power bi create a scd from a table with no historical data?

Tags: powerbi, scd

Can creating a temporal table be done in Power bi instead of SQL?  I want to import data from my organizations employee database(which overwrites changes so there is no historical data).  Compare it in power bi to the table I currently have loaded from a month ago; if it is different, can power bi add a new record to show the SCD with new empl title and then date stamp it for that day?

Comment: No, the ETL process should do that. If you don't have one, you should consider changing the architecture of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically no unfortunately (although you could possibly fake it using dataset partitions, dataflows or programmatically adding records to what's called a "push datasets" - and one of these would be easy nor stable).  Power BI assumes that all data will be purged on a full refresh.